ambiguous partial specializations
I have a big 3rd party library that I am trying to compile with latest clang (version 19) and I keep running into ambiguous partial specializations error. A minimal sample to reproduce the issue looks like this:
#include <type_traits>
#include <vector>

struct Type
{
    template <typename T>
    static Type get() { return {}; }
};

template<typename T>
struct template_type_trait : std::false_type
{
    static std::vector<Type> get_template_arguments() { return {}; }
};

template<template <typename... > class T, typename...Args>
struct template_type_trait<T<Args...>> : std::true_type
{
    static std::vector<Type> get_template_arguments() { return { Type::get<Args>()..., }; }
};

#define ADD_TYPE_TRAIT_SPECIALIZATION(value_type)                                                                                    \
    template<template <value_type> class T, value_type Arg>                                                                                 \
    struct template_type_trait<T<Arg>> : std::true_type                                                                                     \
    {                                                                                                                                       \
        static std::vector<Type> get_template_arguments() { return { Type::get<value_type>() }; }                           \
    };

ADD_TYPE_TRAIT_SPECIALIZATION(std::size_t)
ADD_TYPE_TRAIT_SPECIALIZATION(bool)
ADD_TYPE_TRAIT_SPECIALIZATION(int)
ADD_TYPE_TRAIT_SPECIALIZATION(char)

// //////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
   
template <bool>
struct BB { };

int main()
{
    return template_type_trait<BB<true>>::value;
}

You can also find a live example here: https://godbolt.org/z/hvc6zjj1q
In other compilers (MSVC) and previous versions of clang this is not an issue. Why would the non-type specializations be ambiguous ? Is this a bug in compiler ? It seems that compiling with -fno-relaxed-template-template-args succeeds. Any suggestions for a better work-around/fix ?

"with latest clang (version 19)" It is currently trunk version... latest official is 18.1.8

Yes, but that's the version used by latest emscripten SDK (3.1.64)

So I found a way to compile that code using C++17's template<auto>:
#include <type_traits>
#include <vector>

struct Type
{
    template <typename T>
    static Type get() { return {}; }
};

template<typename T>
struct template_type_trait : std::false_type
{
    static std::vector<Type> get_template_arguments() { return {}; }
};

template<template <typename... > class T, typename...Args>
struct template_type_trait<T<Args...>> : std::true_type
{
    static std::vector<Type> get_template_arguments() { return { Type::get<Args>()..., }; }
};

template<template <auto> class T, auto Arg>
struct template_type_trait<T<Arg>> : std::true_type
{                                                                                                                                       
        static std::vector<Type> get_template_arguments() { return { Type::get<decltype(Arg)>() }; }
};

// //////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
   
template <bool>
struct BB { };

int main()
{
    return template_type_trait<BB<true>>::value;
}


You can even generalize the last partial-specialization by creating a parameter pack, in the form auto... Args. However, it is useful only if such template classes might be used.
